# how we can use Indian rupee symbol in Miktex

Tags: symbols, input-encodings

I am using Miktex and texstudio to typeset.
I have to use this indian rupee symbol in tex file..
But I could not use that in my texstudio.

How to I use it.

**What I am Using??**

1. I am using Windows 8.1 enterprise edition.
2. MiKTeX for LaTeX and TeXStudio as editor.

When I am in MiKTeX it is giving this error:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "integers-decimal-rational".tex
Trying to make PK font tfrupee at 720 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The tfrupee source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font tfrupee could not be created.
Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Under MiKTeX, you probably have simply to run `updmap.exe` from the command map, to update the type 1 fonts database: on installing fonts, it may happen MiKTeX doesn't run it.

Comment: i am using windows 8.1..Can you give me the procedure to update this font database..kindly give full codes for command prompt@bernard

Comment: Just type `upmap.exe` (or `updmap --verbose` if you want to have details) from the command prompt (I don't know to launch the command prompt on Windows 8.1, as I run Windows 7, bt if you don't know, you'll find it in the Help).

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tfrupee}   %% for rupee symbol
\begin{document}
  \rupee
\end{document}
```

[image]

`fontawesome` package provides this symbol too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
  \faRupee
\end{document}
```

Comment: but its not working in my windows verson..its working when i am using linux..means its not working with miktex whereas working with texlive

Comment: @David: I use miktex too and it is working. So no idea. :(

Comment: kindly see my edit question@harish

Comment: @David Try installing the font yourself: https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html

Comment: @David: See the update with `fontawesome` package.